# Quicktime Java dependency using Maven Apache

Tags: java, maven, quicktime

How do you tell Netbeans where the library is?

Using Eclipse I am able to import QTJava.jar and it understand what I want. However, I can't seem to find the relevant dependency using Maven on Netbeans, and don't known how to import a local library.

Answer (score 0):

This is a proprietary library for which no public download or POM file is available. You will have [to import it into your local Maven repository manually](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#importing-jars).

Comment: Could you either link me to where I could learn how to do this, or give me a crash course?

Comment: added a link that hopefully helps.